# IE Compatibility mode cannot be disabled with Apache vhost config

Tags: html, apache, internet-explorer

I am having a big issue trying to disable IE's Compatibility mode.

After much head banging, I have traced the issue down to whether the site is been served as Apache's default config, or as a virtual host.

I know this to be the case as when I access the site with the 'localhost' domain, everything is fine. As soon as I access the very same page via a domain configured in a virtual host - the site renders in Compatibility mode.

Can anyone please shed any light on this crazy issue???

Serving the site as the default host isn't an option.

- Dean

Comment: The first step would be to use a tool like Firebug to see what response headers Apache emits in the two cases. AFAIK, for compatibility mode, Apache would have to be sending the `X-UA-Compatible` header

Comment: The headers are identical in both case. The technique I am currently using is the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> tag in the header. I have also tried setting the header in the apache config. same result.

Comment: @user that sounds weird, unless this is some esoteric IE rule that the `localhost` domain name gets treated differently... Edit: Ah, I was right! See my answer.

Comment: heh, weird isn't the word I have been using a lot of these last couple of days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah-ha!

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> A large number of line-of-business websites are Internet Explorer 7 capable today. In order to preserve compatibility, **Internet Explorer 8 ships with smart defaults based on zone evaluation**. In the default state, all sites on the public internet display in Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode (Compatibility View off) and all intranet websites display in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode (Compatibility View on).
>
> ...
>
> If you navigate to sites on your local intranet like http://myPortal and http://sharepoint/sites/mySite, Internet Explorer 8 identifies itself with a User Agent string of ‘7’, Version Vector of ‘7’, and displays webpages that trigger standards mode in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode. This combination allows webpages that worked correctly in Internet Explorer 7 to continue to do so in IE8.

I'm not commenting this. I'm sure this has some good  real-world reasons, but I still have the urge to hit my head on the desk.

Comment: excellent work. that was it. seems that a couple of the IE browsers here always classed the site in question as intranet.

Comment: I've found you can override this "characteristic" by inserting this in the meta tag:   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8"/>

Answer (score 0):

When a web-site is being served on the local int**ra**net, Internet Explorer will (by default) switch to IE7 compatible mode.

You can use the to disable this *"IE7 on the intranet compatibility mode"* by including the [X-UA-Compatible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications/) response header to your page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-UA-Compatible: IE=8
```

You can also add the **equivlent** of an http response head to your page by including a `meta http-equiv` element to the `HEAD>` of your document. E.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Hello world!</title>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
   </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: If you do include the header

```
| Header           | Value   |
|------------------|---------|
| X-UA-Compatible  | IE=10   |
```

to your html document, you must add it high enough in the `HEAD` before something else happens that locks in the document mode - and you're locked into IE7.

**Wrong example 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

`meta` elements belong inside the `head` element

**Wrong example 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Hello, world!</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="main-73c2257f2d.css" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

The `X-UA-Compatible` element must appear first in the `head`; except for `title` and other `meta` elements.

> The X-UA-Compatible header isn't case sensitive; however, it must appear in the header of the webpage (the HEAD section) before all other elements except for the title element and other meta elements.

**Wrong example 3**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

The conditionals lock the browser into IE7 mode. Remove them.

**Correct**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
   <title>Hello, world!</title>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```