# IE8 standards mode meta tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, doctype

A web application we have for an organisation that is officially upgrading its standard browser from IE6 to IE8 (queue celebrations), we've set all our DOCTYPEs to be `<!DOCTYPE html>` (as well as fixed other html code) and I thought that in IE8 this would cause the page to be rendered in IE8 Standards Mode. However, it is still shown in IE7 Standards mode.

I've added the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">` into the `<head>` section and it still fails to default to IE8 Standards mode. I'm presuming at this stage that there must be a setting (perhaps Group Policy etc) that is forcing the mode.

After reading a hack on an MSDN forum that if you put the meta tag before the `<html>` tag, it correctly displays as IE8 Standards mode, and this worked for me. Is there another way to do this? It just looks terrible seeing the meta tag there...

Here's roughly how each page is made up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could set `X-UA-Compatible` as a HTTP response header, instead of as a meta tag. If you'd like more details on this, let me know (or just Google it).

Comment: Good. I could post an answer if you want to accept it?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you already posted it yourself. You upvoted my other answer to the linked question, that's enough.

Comment: post the answer @thirtydot, it is rightfully yours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could set `X-UA-Compatible` as a HTTP response header, instead of as a meta tag.

This is a much cleaner solution than placing it above the `<html>` tag.

A <strike>confusing</strike> useful blog post concerning `X-UA-Compatible` and its many intricacies:

http://farukat.es/journal/2009/05/245-ie8-and-the-x-ua-compatible-situation

Answer (score 8):

Two possibilities:

- The `meta` tag definitely belongs into the `<head>` section of the document.
- If this is in an Intranet, this may be IE's "Smart default" kicking in. Yes, there is such a thing as smart defaults. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690831/ie-compatibility-mode-cannot-be-disabled-with-apache-vhost-config/4690956#4690956). Because if you're in an Intranet, IE8 will automatically go into IE7 compatibility mode so as not to break the many corporate apps that rely on IE7. Makes sense, right? Right?

Comment: I think you're spot on...you can see how it could be interpreted as making sense. I was just hoping there was a way to **force** it into the correct standards mode in a more correct way. I haven't tried the host header yet though, maybe that's an option.

Comment: @david yeah. Try the host header but before that, the meta tag in the right location, one of those might help.

Comment: Sorry, i'll clarify my question text, but I did try the correct placed meta tag but that it didn't work.

Comment: +1 for "smart default", it does sound like that is related. See a [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966952/ie-css-problem-when-the-site-is-located-at-networkdrive/4967594#4967594) of mine for more details.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot, your answer to the other question was quite helpful