# Border collapse issue in IE 8 compatibility mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I need to display a table with first row underlined.

For that, I am setting border-collapse and setting border only for the first row.

Its working fine in IE 7 and FF. But in IE 8(compatibility mode), the bottom border is broken.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaZqR/)

```
<table style = "border-collapse:collapse;" width="90%" 
    cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

<tbody>
<tr>

<th align="left" style="border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #838584;">Text1</th>
<th align="right" style="border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #838584;">Text2</th>
<th align="right" style="border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #838584;">Text3</th>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note: I tried giving !DOCTYPE as below in my HTML. But, at that time, the page itself was not rendered in IE 8(compatibility mode). Still it worked as expected in IE7 and FF

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Also, Everything works fine in IE 8 standard mode

Comment: Doctypes are never optional for new web pages. Transitional doctypes are for old, deprecated markup. Always use strict.

Comment: @Rob Transitional is almost exactly the same as strict. You were thinking of quirks mode (without a doctype) vs standards mode (with a doctype). There's the difference.

Comment: @MrLister - Transitional is for the validator so it won't flag deprecated markup. New web pages shouldn't be using deprecated markup.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any difference between the table in Firefox 9, IE7 and IE8 (only tested these browsers). Are you using IE8 in standard mode? The border is solid only in IE8 standard mode. Running in IE7 standard or quirks mode on IE8 will break the border where the cells end/begin.

You may want to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987439/ie8-standards-mode-meta-tag) on how to force IE8 to run in standards mode or hit F12 in IE8 to check your current mode in the IE developer tools

Comment: Yes I use IE 8 with compatibility view. +1 for pointing it out. I will update the question.

Comment: BTW, is there a solution that will work on IE7, IE8 standard and IE8 compatible mode ?

Comment: If there were a solution, how would you deliver css for IE8 standard and IE8 compatible? The best and quickest solution is to force IE8 to look at your websites in IE8 standard mode. I'm aware that this could mean a lot of work for you but it's the way to go. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Adding above tag just after DOCTYPE in masterpage worked for me.. Thanks