# How to open local HTML document in IE compatability mode?

Tags: html, file, internet-explorer-8, local, ie8-compatibility-mode

I created a quick and dirty HTML file to demonstrate an issue I am encountering in IE compatibility mode.  When I open it in IE8 from my desktop, it opens in standard mode.  I need to be able to switch it to compatibility mode, but the icon for that disappears when I am viewing a local HTML document.  What's up with that?

**UPDATE**: None of the three proposed solutions has resulted in the compatibility mode icon showing in IE8.  Instead, I have put my code into an .aspx page and executed it through Visual Studio.  Since it's originating from localhost, the browser thinks it is a remote document and is displaying the compatibility icon like I wanted.

However, if anyone can get this to work without having to do that, I am still open to ideas since launching a web app isn't really the ideal solution for me.

Comment: Where exactly is the icon you are talking about?

Comment: It's the broken-looking document icon just to the left of the refresh button in IE8.

Comment: I can't delete this because some users have had upvotes. It's worth keeping this open, you never know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the three proposed solutions has resulted in the compatibility mode icon showing in IE8. Instead, I have put my code into an .aspx page and executed it through Visual Studio. Since it's originating from localhost, the browser thinks it is a remote document and is displaying the compatibility icon like I wanted.

However, if anyone can get this to work without having to do that, I am still open to ideas since launching a web app isn't really the ideal solution for me.

Comment: Both using F12 or `X-UA-Compatible` header work reliably. You *had to* do something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this'll work because of IE's many [crazy exceptions and rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690831/ie-compatibility-mode-cannot-be-disabled-with-apache-vhost-config/4690956#4690956) regarding local files and compatibility mode, but try the [META tag approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode).

In your `<head>`, for example say:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

See [understanding compatibility modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#DCModes) to make sure you pick the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You could try pressing F12 to open the developer toolbar, and change it in there.

**Update**: Have you tried tools > compatibility view settings > display all websites in compatibility view?

Answer (score 1):

> Users can override the ‘local
>   intranet’ setting by un-checking
>   ‘Display intranet sites in
>   Compatibility View’ at Tools ->
>   Compatibility View Settings.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults.aspx