# Virtual server not able to detect browser version

Tags: html, linux, internet-explorer, virtualbox

I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu on my virtual machine (dev server).

I have the following code:

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    U r using an old browser!
  <![endif]-->
```

I'm using IE9 and this works fine on the prod server. But when I test my site on my local dev server, I keep getting the 'old browser' message.

What can cause this?

I found the culprit. It was the IE quirk mode that was causing the headache. The following line solved it:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Comment: thats all client side, it has nothing to do with the server. do you have compatibility mode selected?

Comment: Daniel, why is this working on my production server then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're accessing your local site using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, this could be related to [this bizarre IE behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690831/ie-compatibility-mode-cannot-be-disabled-with-apache-vhost-config/4690956#4690956). Internet Explorer 8 introduced "smart defaults" when it comes to compatibility on local sites:

> A large number of line-of-business websites are Internet Explorer 7 capable today. In order to preserve compatibility, Internet Explorer 8 ships with smart defaults based on zone evaluation. In the default state, all sites on the public internet display in Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode (Compatibility View off) and all intranet websites display in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode (Compatibility View on).

I don't know how IE9 deals with this, but it could be that this is the culprit.

In that case, try accessing your local  dev site using some other domain name (like `stevendev` or something). That should make IE go into normal mode.

Comment: Huh.... didn't know that. My Ubuntu server receives an IP address from DHCP, so I'm not using `localhost` or `127.0.0.2`. I just have to add a check in my PHP file to see if I'm test server on prod server. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Steven hmm, strange. Then it's unlikely it's the reason... You could try forcing compatibility mode to IE9 and seeing whether it works better

Comment: I found the solution. It was because of the quirk mode. Adding this solved it (I think) `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`